# Query help : Running Avg for last 15 days

Tags: sql, t-sql

please help me with a query to find running Avg for every 15 days. I have used below query but not sure how to display only 15 days Avg.

```
Select Date, 
       Avg(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 15 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningAvg
FROM Sample
```

```
Sample Table : (Contains Qty for each Day)
            
Date        Qty   
2014-10-01  4
2014-10-02  5
.. 
..
2014-12-31  4


Expected Result.
Date         RunningAvg 
2014-10-01   4
2014-10-15   XX
2014-11-01   XX
2014-11-15   XX
2014-12-01   XX
.
.
.
```

Comment: In SQL Server, which I suppose you're using, you can use datepart function to extract the day, month and year, then check if it's greater than 15 or not and convert them like: 2014-11-02 => 2014-11-01  and 2014-11-23 => 2014-11-15.

Comment: What about `RANGE BETWEEN 15 PRECEDING` instead of `ROWS`

Comment: I don't see what data on the 1st and 15th of the month has to do with a "running average".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit baffled by the question.  Your results seem to suggest that you want the values on the 1st and 15th of the month -- and that has nothing to do with 15-day moving averages.  For such filtering you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where day(date) in (1, 15);
```

As you know, some months have 28, 29, or 31 days so "15 days" has nothing to do with the day of the months.  And the number of days between the 1st and 15th is 14 days, not 15.